# "if __name__ == '__main__':" suddenly pops up when I enter a new line in PyCharm

Tags: python, python-3.x, ide, pycharm

I'm new to Python and am working on a project using PyCharm. I've repeatedly had the issue that when I simply hit 'return' and create a new line, Pycharm automatically indents my current block of code and throws this above the block: `if __name__ == '__main__':`

[I created a GIF to show what's going on here](https://gfycat.com/UniqueCircularClam).

This has happened a few times without me noticing. I've had to track it down these inserted lines to keep everything working. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: this seems like an issue you should be submitting to the PyCharm bug tracker.